# What single word encompasses all of a person's social media & Internet presence?

Tags: single-word-requests, internet

I'm looking for a **single word** that describes the Internet & Social media presence of a single entity. Their digital footprint, as it were.

Comment: Why must you have a single word? Are you running out of spaces?

Comment: Because that is the question I asked. And yes, it's a space issue.

Comment: To hazard a suggestion: no such single-word exists, so you're going to have to coin one. Whatever you coin is likely to seem awkward at first (e-presence, i-brand, etc), but if it catches on it will eventually seem natural.

Comment: [*Digidentity*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Digidentity) maybe...

Comment: Can you be more specific then as to your length requirement? 20 characters? 10?

Comment: Is a non-digital footprint one with no toes?

Comment: It's less a character count limitation than one of brevity. Four words sounds awkward on my business card. Three, less so.

Comment: @Chenmunka, there is no limitation on space in the English language, true. But why use two words when one will do?

Comment: @zenbike Because one word doesn't exist, unless you coin a neologism. *Online Presence* is succinct enough for a business card.

Comment: Business card? Is this a job title or a listed service? What do you have so far? *Internet & Social media presence Guru*? *Data Specialist*? *fix your cloud clout*?

Comment: @Mazura: Tag line.  "Own your Digital Identity" is the intent, but doesn't quite fit for me.

Comment: @ghoppe: If that is the case, then 2 words are required.  That is why it is a question.  If I had the answer, I wouldn't need to ask.

Comment: Maybe "VirtualiD", playing on virtuality?

Comment: What do you mean by "own"; like pwned? What services do you offer? Purchasing data rights? "Own" doesn't work so well for my answer; it became "be".

Comment: If it's a space issue, you can use IID, which stands for "[internet identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_identity)" or "internet persona", which is the perfect phrase for what you want.

Answer (score 5):

It is called: [Digital presence](http://blog.limelight.com/2012/07/what-is-a-digital-presence/):

> - Plain and simple, ***a digital presence is everything digital about you***. For most of us, that is what we do on the Web. Whether it’s through Facebook or Twitter or a blog or comments on a video. And there are even services out there, like Klout and BrandYourself, that attempt to measure the effectiveness of our digital presence.

or [Cyberlife](http://www.wordsense.eu/cyberlife/) according to:(www.wordsense.eu)

> - Life in cyberspace or on the Internet, as opposed to real life, ***often lived through a separate cyberidentity***.

Comment: Right concept, but I need a way to say it in a single word, as stated in the question.

Comment: @ zenbike -        I don't think there is a single word for that, but I am still checking.

Comment: Apparently, [***my online presence*** is far more common than ***my digital presence***](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=%22my+digital+presence%22&word2=%22my+online+presence%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers . that is because it is just *yours* : http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=digital+presence&word2=online+presence

Comment: Nah! *Yours* gives the wrong answer because you didn't put quotes around the two "contestants" in the GoogleFight. So all it proves is that *in general*, ***digital*** is a far more common word than ***online***. [Herewith](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=%22your+digital+presence%22&word2=%22your+online+presence%22), I rest my case that both your and my online presences are more pervasive than our digital presences.

Answer (score 4):

cyberself

homemade word that is self explanatory.

Comment: Actually Wiktionary defines cyberself as: *an alternate self on the Internet or in cyberspace; an online alter-ego*. http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cyberself

Comment: Well there you go!

Comment: Well, it looks like this is the closest it gets. Maybe you can include the definition from Wiktionary and include the synonym *cyberidentity* that is mentioned there also.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a single word. Perhaps "digital footprint" or "digital shadow"

Comment: Right concept, but I need a way to say it in a single word, as stated in the question.

Answer (score 2):

"cyberpresence" seems like it might fit

Answer (score 0):

I usually fall back to fake German for single words that mean complicated things - how does *Digitalgesamtauftritt* grab you?

Comment: "digitalurgestalt" would be close. But English, is a requirement. :)

Comment: Just being pedantic: the [ur-](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ur-) prefix denotes a proto/primal state, which is to say "digitalurgestalt" would more suggest an earlier "draft" form of your digital presence.  So "digitalurgestalt" is actually a perfect word for say, someone's myspace profile.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard and used these terms:
Identity and edentity - self explanatory I believe..

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please add references to support your answer.